# How to calculate the dirrerence between two columns

Tags: hive

I have a table which contains data for two months

[image]

Write a query to find the change in revenue generated due to purchases from October to November.

With data as((Select month(event_time) as month_value, sum(price) as octrevenue from retailfinal where event_type = 'purchase' and  month(event_time) = 10 group by month(event_time)) union (Select month(event_time) as month_value, sum(price) as novrevenue from retailfinal where event_type = 'purchase' and  month(event_time) = 11 group by month(event_time))) select *,(novrevenue-octrevenue) as diff from data ;

Whats wrong in above query ?

Answer (score 1):

Sql has few problems.

1. You are doing union sep and oct values and then subtract them. Its not possible. You need to calculate them in same row.
2. Month without year is worthless and can give you wrong results for data for multiple years. So sum should be grouped by year.
3. Where conditik  should be on initcapped event_type  =Purchase . Otherwise it will never find a match.

Now, the solution for your issue is below. This will give you difference for a year. Depending on your requirements, you can add columns to group by. If you want all columns, you need to join below query with retail table.

```
Select yr, octsum-septsum as diff
From
(Select
Sum(case when lower(sep.event_type) = 'purchase' and 
month(event_time)=10 then price else 0 end ) octsum,
Sum(case when lower(sep.event_type) = 'purchase' and 
month(event_time)=9 then price else 0 end ) septsum,
Year(event_time) yr
From 
retailfinal 
Group by Year(event_time) 
)Rs
```